# How can I extract a tag's attribute value from an HTML file?

Tags: regex, bash

I know, don't parse using curl, grep and sed. But I am looking for an easy approach, not a very safe one.

So I get an HTML file with curl, from which I need a value of a certain attribute from a tag. I use grep to get me the line where it says `token`. This only occurs once.
This gives me a whole div:

```
<div class="userlinks">
  <span class="arrow flleft profilesettings">settings</span>
  <form class="logoutform" method="post" action="/logout">
    <input class="logoutbtn arrow flright" type="submit" value="Log out">
    <input type="hidden" name="ltoken" value="a5fc8828a42277538f1352cf9ea27a71">
  </form>
</div>
```

How can I get just the value attribute (e.g. "a5fc8828a42277538f1352cf9ea27a71")?

Comment: The edit by @CodeGnome makes the code more readable but misses the intent of the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no need to grep:

```
sed -n '/token/s/.*name="ltoken"\s\+value="\([^"]\+\).*/\1/p' input_file
```

Comment: This does not return anything unfortunately. I even copied just the line into a file and used your command. But no output.

Comment: @perreal : And what about the case where the value attribute precede the name inside the tag?

Comment: I can't get this work on OS X (doesn't return anything), even with a trivial example like `sed -n '/token/s/.*name="ltoken"\s\+value="\([^"]\+\).*/\1/p' <<< '<input type="hidden" name="ltoken" value="a5fc8828a42277538f1352cf9ea27a71">'`. Anyone got a clue to why sed behaves differently? That same line works fine on my Linux boxes, though. OS X has the BSD version of sed (and not the GNU version).

Answer (score 10):

One way, using `sed`:

```
sed "s/.* value=\"\(.*\)\".*/\1/" file.txt
```

Results:

```
a5fc8828a42277538f1352cf9ea27a71
```

HTH

Comment: use [^"]* instead of .* inside the group if you want to match only the string before the next quotation mark - i.e. before not the last

Answer (score 5):

Another way using `awk`

```
grep "ltoken" file.txt | awk -F"\"" '{print $6}'
```

For different attribute value just increase or decrease the value of `$6`

Answer (score 4):

#### Use XPath Expression and a Dash of Grep

You can actually parse the HTML properly from the command line. For example, you can use [xgrep](http://wohlberg.net/public/software/xml/xgrep/) to create an xpath expression, and then use GNU sed (or your grep of choice) to extract just the text you care about. For example:

```
$ xgrep -x '//input[@name="ltoken"][1]/@value' /tmp/foo |
      sed -rn '/value/ s/.*"([[:xdigit:]]+)"/\1/p'
a5fc8828a42277538f1352cf9ea27a71
```

Comment: Nice (I must learn more XPath one of these days), but you should point out that `xgrep` may not be installed by default.

Answer (score 2):

There is one problem with the xgrep solution in that it expects valid xml. The provided html isn't valid because of the unclosed 'input' elements.
[xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) has a html parser option and also provides the string() function to extract the value without the use of sed.

```
$ xmllint --html --xpath 'string(//input[@name="ltoken"][1]/@value)' foo
a5fc8828a42277538f1352cf9ea27a71
```

Comment: And what about the case where the value attribute is before`name=` inside the tag?

Comment: The order of the attributes doesn't matter. This is a xpath expression, not a regex expression. First the input tag with name='ltoken' is selected, then the content of the 'value' attribute is returned.

Comment: xmllint performing xml document validation before parsing and not suitable for external page which not comply to W3C standards.